# Recognize keystrokes in Android Soft Keyboard using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, keystroke

I am a student and I am currently building an Android application with Kotlin as the programming language. The application's aim will be to register keystrokes from users which I will use for biometric research purpose. I am not proficient in Kotlin or Android Studio as this is the first time I am working in Android Studio.

The application has many activities and I am sharing the code from one of the activities, where I need to recognize the keystrokes in Editexts, while the user presses keys in soft keyboard to type username and password.

I found some Android Developers examples about [KeyEvents](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands) and some [References](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent).

The data I need from the keystrokes are as follows:

```
    a. the key pressed. 
    b. key pressed time. 
    c. key released time. 
    d. its ASCII value.
```

The XML Code is as follows:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pt_mono"
    android:onClick="resetval"
    android:text="@string/reset"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.007" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pt_mono"
    android:onClick="input"
    android:text="@string/inp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText9"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText9" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText8"
    android:imeOptions="normal"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pt_mono"
    android:hint="@string/usrname"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView21"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView21"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView21" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_text"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pt_mono"
    android:hint="@string/pass"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editText8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText8" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pt_mono"
    android:text="@string/train_tem"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/btext"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

The Kotlin code is as follows:

```
class trainingT : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    supportActionBar?.title = "Training Template"
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_training_t)
    //getuserkeystroke()
}
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    return when (keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D -> {
            getuserkeystroke(keyCode)
            true
        }
        else -> super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    }
}
private fun getuserkeystroke(keyCode: Int){
    Log.d("D should be displayed", "Is it displayed?")//keyCode.toString())
    val toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "D is Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    val layout = toast.getView() as LinearLayout
    if (layout.childCount > 0) {
        val tv = layout.getChildAt(0) as TextView
        tv.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL or Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    }
    toast.show()
}}
```

So far I am stuck on point number "a". I am missing something I know that, as the key pressed has to be recognized inside the Editext space, but I have no idea how to. The Kotlin code should call the getuserkeystroke() function as soon as "d key" (I was thinking of recognizing at least a single key and after that random keys) is pressed, display a debug message in the log and should show a toast but its not working.

Please suggest how should I proceed in order to recognize the keys pressed in the Android soft keyboard when typing in real time? And also some suggestions on how to acquire the data I mentioned in points "b", "c" and "d".

The activity screenshot is as follows: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aOl1.png)

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this. It qualifies as spying and Android prevents that. If you want to know what a user is typing, you need to use your own keyboard.

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. I will look into that. @TheWanderer

Comment: @TheWanderer Thank you again. I looked up what you suggested. There are a ton of references on building custom soft keyboard and it seems that I can control the onKeyPress and onKeyRelease functions in the .java ot .kt file. I just found something interesting that I could build my keyboard as a service. I wanted to ask you that, is it possible to bundle my app with the keyboard service into a single apk file? Please suggest some references where I can find the technical knowledge to do it as I have no idea how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add an input method to your app, yes. Just follow any tutorial by adding the necessary classes and declarations to your current app.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your help is much appreciated @TheWanderer